# Form Shrinking Issue After using a Custom ImageListView Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I'm using the following control for loading images in winforms.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43265/ImageListView

(OR)

https://github.com/oozcitak/imagelistview

It seems on a 1080P 15" Laptop there exists some scaling issue related to this control which is not reproducible on a 24" 1080P Monitor

I have recently noticed an odd thing happening with form scaling. It happens with the master solution downloaded directly from GitHub, and in my own application. My PC display setting is set to scale the display to 125% (right click desktop -> Display Settings -> Change the size of text, apps, and ...)

When I start debugging, the form loads - correctly scaled. However, as soon as I click on a folder in the treeview which has images, the images are loaded, and the form is scaled back to 100%. So the whole form appears to instantly shrink, while the rest of Windows is still at 125%.

I am not sure if this is a Windows or .Net Framework bug, or just the way the control is implemented. Or maybe there is a property I am not aware of that needs to be changed?

Any help / advise would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

After using the DpiAware Option

[image]

Without using DpiAware Option

[image]

Comment: Does this behaviour occur with the standard TreeView control - or in fact any of the standard Windows controls?  If not I would sugest that this points a big finger at the custom control you are using ...

Comment: @SpaceUser7448 This only happens when I use this particular control...

Comment: You might want to see if you can look at the source code - I suspect a bug in there somewhere ...

Comment: @SpaceUser7448 I don't have any idea where to look...

Comment: @Ozgur Ozcitak Thanks for the great control,it helps me a lot.Could you please help me with this issue.It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Codeproject.com code notoriously need to have the [only-works-on-my-machine] tag but this isn't exactly very normal behavior.  You must document your question better to get help.  Add the Resize event for the form and set a breakpoint on.  Press F5 to keep running until you are ready to trigger the behavior.  Post the content of the debugger's Call Stack window.

Comment: If you could switch to XAML your problems would disappear :D

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks will post it..

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Not an option right now..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been able to reproduce the issue and it is a bit strange.  As I suspected the application is not declared to be DPI-aware and setting it to be DPI-aware resolves the issue of the form changing size.  This can be done by adding a manifest file to the project (Project Menu->Add New Item->General Tab->Select "Application Manifest File".  Then add the follow to the file:

```
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

That clears up the issue, but I was curious as to why the code was behaving this way.  The process starts out as DPI-unaware and after closing the image selection dialog, it some how switched to being a DPI-aware process.  The can be observed using the SysInternal's Process Explorer application.  My first thought was to to search for a call to [SetProcessDpiAwareness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302122(v=vs.85).aspx), but that yielded no results.  Digging into the code revealed that the `InitViaWpf` method in `MetadataExtractor.cs` is called.  This method and others utilize classes from the `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` namespace.  It appears that this usage of the WPF libraries causes the application to become DPI-aware in the same way that WPF applications are DPI-aware by default.  There is a conditional compilation symbol declared for the `ImageListView` project named **USEWIC** that controls this usage of the WPF classes.  Removing this symbol in the project's properties build configuration will prevent their usage and can be used as an alternative solution and may be preferable to declaring the Winform application as being DPI-aware, but I don't have the time to investigate this library further.

---

Edit:  This behavior can be easily replicated by creating an instance of [BitmapFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapframe(v=vs.110).aspx) in a Winform application that has not been marked as being DPI-aware.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
        public Form1()
            {
            InitializeComponent();
            }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            using (Stream strm = File.OpenRead("someimage.jpg"))
                {
                BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(strm, BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile, BitmapCacheOption.None);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

---

Edit 2:  Procedure for DPI-aware winform scaling.

Step 1:  In the designer, set the AutoScaleMode property to Inherit.  I know None would make sense, but Inherit is the true default setting.

Step 2:  Modify the Form's constructor to use either Dpi or Font automatic scaling. This is done to prevent the designer from recording improper AutoScaleDimensions.

```
public Form1()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    // Select either Dpi or font scaling
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(96, 96);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;

    //this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0F, 13.0F);
    //this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
```

### }

Edit 3:  To maintain the DPI-virtualization (prevent the automatic switching to DPI-aware) on a DPI-unaware application that uses WPF libraries, include the `dpiAware` section in the app.manifest file, but explicity set it to false.

```
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

Comment: @TnTinMn Thanks a lot for your answer and the hardwork.I have downloaded the ImageListView Project,Added the Manifest as you have told me and rebuilt the Control dll.I added this dll to the main project.. but it seems the issue is not fixed.The form is shrinking just like before.What im i doing wrong? Please advice

Comment: @techno, you should create the manifest on your winform application not the library.  Do note that if you do this that the form will start off and stay at the smaller size unless your form is properly configured to scale based on DPI.

Comment: @TnTinMn Thanks.. i tried that and it works :) ..but as you said the Form is smaller .... how can i fix it?

Comment: @techno, try the procedure described in my 2nd edit to the answer.

Comment: @TnTinMn It produces the same results.Even though the form has gotten little smaller in width all the controls are laid out properly.I have set the DPI Scaling in the form property as i need the app to work in smaller resolutions as well.I was having a button control shrinking issue when DPI setting was used as `AutoScaleMode` but your answer has fixed this too.I will keep it like this ... Thanks a loaaaaattttttt :)

Comment: @TnTinMn I have come across a new issue after adding the DPIAWARE setting.The text has gotten sharper and the icon(Icon on the Winform) appears distorted.Any idea why this happens..? Please see the updated question.. Please advice...

Comment: @techno, most people would not consider sharper text an issue.  As far as why your icon appears distorted, I can only guess that is a large pixel icon that is being scaled down to 16x16 and this is causing the distortion.  I've edited the answer to give you a new option to maintain the DPI-virtualization when using the WPF libraries as well.

Comment: @TnTinMn Thanks a lot..The icon seems to be scaled down.I will check your update and get back.

Comment: @TnTinMn Thanks a lot your solution,It worked perfectly :)  All the issues are sorted now;including a background image sizing issue.As of the icon, it seems to appear smooth.Anyway i will replace it with a version that has 16X16 size.Once again thanks for the hard work,it has really helped me out.