# Unusual Glitch when Opening Forms

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

When I maximise a form in my project and open another form from it (using a button), I'm getting an unusual glitch which I can only explain with the use of the screenshots below.

In this image, I have got an order screen and a freight screen. The order screen is maximised into an MDI screen when I hit the 'Add Freight' button, then upon opening the freight management screen, it is setting both forms to `WindowState.Normal`, which I'm doing programmatically and I understand why it sets both forms to normal window state, however, as you can, it is leaving a trace of the order screen behind in maximised view.

To explain more clearly, the forms have been changed from `WindowState.Maximized` to `WindowState.Normal`, and in the image the form in the top left corner is fine, but the order form is still showing in both normalised and maximised, but the maximised window doesn't exist, it disappears when you move the other screens around.

The strangest thing about this is that I'm using the same code to open other windows in the exact same way elsewhere in the program yet this glitch isn't happening.

There are only 2 "parent" forms which do this when opening other forms from within them.

Has anyone else ever had this issue? What is a way around it? This also happens even if I open the other form in maximised mode, so it's not as simple as just opening it in maximised view.

[image]

The code to open the form in the example is the following:

```
ugProducts.UpdateData()

  Try
     Dim dt As New DataTable
     dt = ugProducts.DataSource

     Dim ordnum As Integer
     Dim osql As New OleDbCommand
     osql.CommandType = CommandType.Text

     osql.Connection = con
     osql.CommandText = "SELECT [Order_Number] FROM [Order_Freight] WHERE [Order_Reference] = ?"
     osql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@onum", lblReference.Text.ToString)

     ordnum = Convert.ToInt32(osql.ExecuteScalar)

     Dim ORef As String
     ORef = lblReference.Text

     Dim FNumber As Integer

     Dim fsql As New OleDbCommand
     fsql.CommandType = CommandType.Text

     fsql.Connection = con
     fsql.CommandText = "SELECT [Freight_Number] FROM [Order_Freight] WHERE [Order_Reference] = ?"
     fsql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fnum", lblReference.Text.ToString)

     FNumber = Convert.ToInt32(fsql.ExecuteScalar)

     Dim PC As String
     Try
         PC = ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("Product_Code").Text.ToString
     Catch
         PC = ugProducts.Rows(0).Cells("Product_Code").Text.ToString
     End Try

     Dim SC As String
     Try
         SC = ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("Supplier_Code").Text.ToString
     Catch
          SC = ugProducts.Rows(0).Cells("Supplier_Code").Text.ToString
     End Try

     Dim f As New frmEditFreight(con, dt, Me, cmbCustCode.Text, ordnum, ORef, FNumber, PC, SC)
     f.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
     f.Show()

 Catch ex As Exception
     errorLog(ex)

 End Try
```

Then, on the form that is loaded, I have this

```
   Me.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal

    txtTotal.ReadOnly = True
    lftable = New DataTable

    If isNewOrder = False Then
        Try
            For Each dc As DataColumn In lineTable.Columns
                If dc.ColumnName = "Order_Number" OrElse dc.ColumnName = "Product_Code" OrElse dc.ColumnName = "Supplier_Code" Then
                    lftable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType))
                End If
            Next

            Dim product As String = ""
            Dim supplier As String = fOrder.cmbSupplier.Text

            Dim ds As New DataSet

            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Order_Freight] WHERE [Order_Number] = ?", con)
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@num", OleDbType.Integer).Value = orderNum
            da.Fill(ds)
            Dim nDt As New DataTable
            nDt = ds.Tables(0).Copy()

            For Each row As DataRow In nDt.Rows
                product = row.Item("Product_Code")

                For Each dr As DataRow In lineTable.Rows
                    If dr.RowState <> DataRowState.Deleted Then
                        If dr.Item("Product_Code") = product Then
                            dr.Delete()
                        Else
                        End If
                    Else
                        If dr.Item("Product_Code", DataRowVersion.Original) = product Then
                            dr.Delete()
                        Else
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            For Each dr As DataRow In lineTable.Rows
                If dr.RowState <> DataRowState.Deleted Then
                    dr.Item("Order_Number") = orderNum
                End If
            Next

            Me.ugProducts.DataSource = lineTable

            For Each dc As UltraGridColumn In ugProducts.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns
                Dim cName As String = dc.ToString

                Select Case cName
                    Case "Product_Code"
                        dc.Hidden = False
                    Case "Order_Number"
                        dc.Hidden = False
                    Case "Supplier_Code"
                        dc.Hidden = False
                    Case Else
                        dc.Hidden = True
                End Select
            Next

            loadAddresses(custCode, con)

            dtEstDelivery.Value = Date.Today

            ugProducts.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Override.CellClickAction = CellClickAction.RowSelect

            selectedTable.Columns.Add("Product_Code")
            selectedTable.Columns.Add("Supplier_Code")
            selectedTable.Columns.Add("RowIndex")

            freightTable = New DataTable

            With freightTable.Columns
                .Add("Freight_Number")
                .Add("Address_Code")
                .Add("Est_Delivery")
                .Add("Product_Code")
                .Add("Freight_Desc")
                .Add("Freight_Val", GetType(Decimal))
                .Add("Supplier_Code")
                .Add("freeDelivery", GetType(Boolean))
            End With

            ugFreight.DataSource = freightTable

            ugSelected.DataSource = selectedTable
            ugSelected.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Override.CellClickAction = CellClickAction.RowSelect

        Catch ex As Exception
            errorLog(ex)

        End Try
    Else
        Try
            Me.ugProducts.DataSource = lineTable

            For Each dc As UltraGridColumn In ugProducts.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns
                Dim cName As String = dc.ToString

                Select Case cName
                    Case "Product_Code"
                        dc.Hidden = False
                    Case "Product_Description"
                        dc.Hidden = False
                        dc.Header.Caption = "Description"
                    Case "Supplier_Code"
                        dc.Hidden = False
                        dc.Header.Caption = "Supplier"
                    Case Else
                        dc.Hidden = True
                End Select
            Next

            loadAddresses(custCode, con)

            dtEstDelivery.Value = Date.Today

            ugProducts.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Override.CellClickAction = CellClickAction.RowSelect

            selectedTable.Columns.Add("Product_Code")
            selectedTable.Columns.Add("Supplier_Code")
            selectedTable.Columns.Add("RowIndex")

            freightTable = New DataTable

            With freightTable.Columns
                .Add("Freight_Number")
                .Add("Address_Code")
                .Add("Est_Delivery")
                .Add("Product_Code")
                .Add("Freight_Desc")
                .Add("Freight_Val", GetType(Decimal))
                .Add("Supplier_Code")
                .Add("freeDelivery", GetType(Boolean))
            End With

            ugFreight.DataSource = freightTable

            ugSelected.DataSource = selectedTable
            ugSelected.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Override.CellClickAction = CellClickAction.RowSelect

        Catch ex As Exception
            errorLog(ex)

        End Try
    End If

    bLoading = False
```

Followed by some ordinary stuff, setting `DataTables`, loading in data, etc.

The other form which is having the issue has this code:

```
 Try
    Dim grid As UltraGrid = DirectCast(sender, UltraGrid)
    Dim lastElement As UIElement = ugRates.DisplayLayout.UIElement.LastElementEntered
    Dim rowElement As RowUIElement

    If TypeOf lastElement Is RowUIElement Then
         rowElement = DirectCast(lastElement, RowUIElement)
    Else
         rowElement = DirectCast(lastElement.GetAncestor(GetType(RowUIElement)), RowUIElement)
    End If

     If rowElement Is Nothing Then Return

     Dim row As UltraGridRow = DirectCast(rowElement.GetContext(GetType(UltraGridRow)), UltraGridRow)

     If (row Is Nothing) Then Return

     Dim MousePosition As Point = grid.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)

     If Not lastElement.AdjustableElementFromPoint(MousePosition) Is Nothing Then Return

 Select Case row.Cells("cType").Value
     Case "Acquisition Rate"
       Dim supplier As String

       If rbtnAllSuppliers.Checked = True Then
          supplier = row.Cells("Supp_Code").Value
       Else
          supplier = cmbSupplier.Text
       End If

       Dim f As New frmCommission(con, row.Cells("Comm_Code").Value, supplier, True)
       f.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
       f.Show()
```

With the rest of the select case below. The form being opened in this case then has the code

```
  Me.Location = New Point(0, 0)
  Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
  Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default

  isUpdate = False

  Me.ugComm.ContextMenuStrip = cmCommRate

  With updateDT.Columns
      .Add("Apply", GetType(Boolean)).DefaultValue = False
      .Add("Product_Code")
      .Add("Commission_Rate")
      .Add("Multiplier")
  End With

  btnCustomerSearch.Enabled = False

  Try
      Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
      Dim ds As New DataSet

      sql = "SELECT * FROM [System Settings]"
      da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

      Dim dt As New DataTable
      da.Fill(dt)

      If dt.Rows(0).Item("enableAqDate") = False Then
          rbtnAcq.Enabled = False
      End If

      If cCode <> "" And sCode <> "" Then
          cmbSupp.Text = sCode
          cmbSupp_ValueChanged(sender, New EventArgs)
      End If

      disableControls()

      cmbSupp.Refresh()
      txtCommCode.Refresh()
      ugComm.Refresh()
      cmbSupp.Enabled = False

      isLoad = False

      If isEnquiry = True Then
          txtCommCode.Text = cCode
          loadEnquiry()
          ugComm.Enabled = True
          cmdAddRange.Enabled = False
          cmdUpdateRange.Enabled = True
          cmbSupp.Value = sCode
          txtCommCode.Text = cCode
      End If

  Catch ex As Exception
      errorLog(ex)

  End Try
```

When trying to insert the code suggested for making `dpiaware = True`, I've not been able to see anywhere in the code that this would go?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code you're having the issue with?  As odd as it is, I've had to add `Application.DoEvents()` to this type of situation as one form may require more memory, and time to load, than the next.

Comment: You have to show us the code that creates these forms.  Any paint code?  Any resize code?

Comment: @JimmySmith Code added.

Comment: @LarsTech nope, not any of that sort of code, I've posted what I do have.

Comment: If the application is not DPI-aware, try making it so and please report back the results.  The artifacts could be caused by DPI virtualization.

Comment: Have you tried adding an `Application.DoEvents` call right before you show the child form as @JimmySmith suggested?

Comment: @Mike_OBrien Yeah, even adding `Application.DoEvents()` between `f.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent` and `f.Show()` still causes the glitch.

Comment: @TnTinMn How do I do that? I've looked at a few tutorials online, none of them seem to work, all erroring when building the solution it messages "This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect"

Comment: `How do I do that?`--> Project Menu->"Proj Name" Properties->Application Tab->Click on the "View Window Settings" Button.  This will open the "app.manifest" file.  In VS2015 or VS2017, scroll down about 1/2 way through the file to find the DPI settings and un-comment the `<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">` block that contains the `dpiaware` node.  In earlier versions you need to add this block to the file; for an example of the text to add [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42511167/2592875)..

Comment: @TnTinMn That's what I was trying earlier, see in the screenshot I've added in (You'll need to open it in a new tab to see it clearly), this code isn't in the file - Where does it go? After the <application> tag?

Comment: David, just copy the block from the earlier referenced post and paste it just before the `</asmv1:assembly>` tag at the end of the file.  The placement in the file is not special, you just need place such that it does not become meshed into the other blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit seems to be setting the `WindowState` property to `Normal` inside the `Load` event of a mdi child form when active mdi child form is maximized.

At this time the target form is in some intermediate state - the event is called as part of the window handle creation, the handle is already created, `Visible` property is `True` (but the form is not really shown on screen), `WindowState` returns `Maximized` and trying to set it to `Normal` leads internally to `ShowWindow` API call.

It's hard to tell where exactly is the bug (there are a lot of internal flags and windows messages handling inside the `Form` class), but the end effect is that the `MDIClient` and the currently active mdi child form are not correctly invalidated, hence the visual effect you are experiencing.

With that being said, there are several workarounds:

*(1) At the form being shown side:*

Move the `Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal` to the [`Shown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

*(2) At the caller side:*

(A) Add `Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal` before `f.Show()`

or

(B) Add `Me.MdiParent.Invalidate(True)` after `f.Show()`

or

(C) Add `Me.MdiParent.Refresh()` after `f.Show()`

My personal preference would be the option (1) since it encapsulates a logic which is specific to the called form inside that form.