# Fitting a 1148X809 Form in 1366x768 Resolution Screen(15inch Laptop Screen)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, window

I have a winforms application whose window size is 1148X809 Pixels.When a user with 1366X768 Resolution uses the application,the bottom portion of the window gets cut off.

To solve this issue I have referred to this solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42511167/848968
and added `DPIAware` option in the manifest file ,set `AutoscaleMode` to inherit.But this does not seem to solve the problem.I have also came across an article about new Winforms DPI Scaling Update in .net 4.7
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms

Can you please help me to get this issue sorted.

Comment: Do you mean you intend your entire window to appear smaller (e.g. 90% height textboxes, etc.)?

Comment: I highly recommend to switch to WPF, because a simple form-resize can be managed by it via a Grid and a relative width/length. I often create my applications with a size of 1024x576 because the resizing is very simple

Comment: @John yeah,the entire window without any text being cut off

Comment: @Shmosi Switching to WPF is not an option.

Comment: How about use Dock or Anchor on All of your Controls?

Comment: @Arphile That does not solve the issue unless the form is set to Maximized.

Comment: @techno, a screenshot of your application would help from VS design mode. @Arphile mentions Docking and Anchoring your controls, you may also wish to look at a `TableLayoutPanel` in conjunction. This will assist in keeping your controls in the correct places when the form is resized.

Comment: @HandbagCrab Does the new update in .net 4.7 fix DPI Issues?

Comment: @techno, I have no idea. This sounds more like bad layout than a DPI issue (because there are no screenshots to go on). For instance, what happens to your application on your screen when you resize it so it is only half height? Do the controls at the bottom get cut off?

Comment: This doesn't look like a DPI awareness problem. Your Form is too large. You have to provide means to resize it. WinForms has its tools for this. If you already have modified your app.manifest to specify DPI awareness, the System won't interfere in your design. .Net 4.7.1+ won't change anything here. You, simply, have to create a different, more flexible, layout. Resize your Forms when you detect a screen size change. You never know on what screen your app will end up to and what its size will be.

Comment: @HandbagCrab The window can't be resized ,it's fixed.

Comment: @techno, that's your issue then, no amount of DPI awareness is going to fix that. Your window is too big to fit on anything other than a screen your size or larger. As the comments have been saying to you, you need to revise how your window is layed out so that it can be resized, then your problem will go away. If you post a screenshot from VS we may be able to assist.

Comment: @HandbagCrab okay... Thanks

Comment: Since you have `AutoscaleMode` set to Inherit, you could add a call to the [Control.Scale Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.scale?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Scale_System_Drawing_SizeF_) with the proper factor based on Screen's `WorkingArea` dimensions at the end of the constructor method.  Also apply the scale factor to the used fonts.